# Database clustered Index on referring column

Tags: database, indexing

I have two tables like this.

### Table A

A_ID ( Primary Key)
A1
A2

### Table B

B_ID ( Primary Key)
B1
B2
A_ID ( foreign key but not enforced in database, not unique )

Although by default SQL server creates clustered indexes on B_ID, I have lot of select queries on B, which depend on A_ID

something like this

SELECT * FROM B WHERE B.A_ID = 'SOME ID'

Should I be creating clustered Index on A_ID of TABLE B  ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No a regular non-clustered index should do fine. A clustered index is especially handy when doing range queries (BETWEEN) As a rule of thumb I always create non-clustered indexes on columns used in foreign key constraints.

Comment: +1 good recommendation! (the index on foreign key columns) - this is not done automatically, contrary to a lot of folks' belief

Answer (score 3):

No, just create a normal non-clustered index - you'll have basically the same results and same improvements in your query speed.

Is the A_ID on table B even guaranteed to be unique?? Couldn't more than 1 entry in "B" reference the same A_ID ??

Best practice for a clustered key is:

- as small as possible (narrow)
- unique
- stable (or static - it should never change)
- ever increasing

See Kim Tripp's [The Clustered Index Debate continues](http://sqlskills.com/BLOGS/KIMBERLY/post/The-Clustered-Index-Debate-Continues.aspx) or [Ever-increasing clustering key - the Clustered Index Debate - agin!](http://www.sqlskills.com/BLOGS/KIMBERLY/post/Ever-increasing-clustering-key-the-Clustered-Index-Debateagain!.aspx) for additional info.

If your clustered key cannot be guaranteed to be unique, SQL Server will add a 4-byte uniquifier to it - you'll want to avoid that whenever possible (because your clustering key will be added to every single entry of every single non-clustered index on your table, leading to waste of space if it's too wide).

Marc